# Clarification needed about generating jax-ws client stubs in order to consume a webservice

Tags: wsdl, jax-ws, wsimport, jax-ws-customization, jaxws-maven-plugin

I have on the one hand a **wsdl url/file** and on the other hand a number of **xsd schema files** (are the latte called binding files?).

All of these **describe a webservice** that I would like to **consume using jax-ws**.

I understand I need to **generate client stubs** using the **wsimport utility**.

I have a **requirement** for **one distinct package per xsd schema/binding file** for the generated stubs files. The generated stubs for the wsdl would be located in another package.

1. Does that make sense?
2. Is this possible? If so how?
3. I am missing something?

**edit**: I don't fully understand the difference of intent between files generated against the wsdl and files generated against the xsd binding files as when using wsimport. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 0):

baleto

first thing the xjb files are used to resolve conflicts and customizing schemas.

You can create a distinct package for a XSD if it has a specfic namespace defined for it.

For example you need a package name like com.foo.healthcare.claims then you need to have a name space for the schema as http://www.foo.com/healthcare/claims.